# What does "precious rascals" mean in "The Blue Scarab"?

Tags: meaning, short-stories, r-austin-freeman, dr-thorndyke

In "[The Blue Scarab](https://archive.org/details/bluescarab00free/page/n13/mode/2up)" in *Dr. Thorndyke's Case-Book* by R. Austin Freeman, Mr. Blowgrave, whose deed-box was stolen, was talking to Dr. Thorndyke:

> "The story concerns my great-grandfather Silas Blowgrave, and his doings during the war with France. It seems that he commanded a privateer of which he and his brother Reuben were the joint owners, and that in the course of their last cruise they acquired a very remarkable and valuable collection of jewels. Goodness knows how they got them; not very honestly, I suspect, for they appear to have been a pair of **precious rascals**. Something has been said about the loot from a South American church or cathedral, but there is really nothing known about the affair.

I've never met the word "precious" with a bad adjective, **does it mean "great"** or something like that?

Comment: maybe you've come across "precious little", as in "very little"

Comment: It's a rather endearing phrase nowadays.

Comment: Precious is sometimes used to stand for 'precoscious' or synonyms inferring 'cupidity'.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> **precious, *adj.* 4.** *colloquial.* a. As an intensifier: complete, utter, out-and-out.
>
> <sub>*Oxford English Dictionary*</sub>

Comment: Any info on the usage in this context *over time*? To me it feels quite old-fashioned now, in that sense as an adjective. (A bit more common as an *adverb*, in phrases like "precious few".)

Answer (score 6):

The Thorndyke stories are set in the early 20th century (contemporaneous with the author).

At this time, "precious" was used as a magnifier as described in the [earlier answer](https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/15119/10632) (which I lack the rep to add context in comments to, hence the separate answer).

Additional negative meanings can be the current pretentious/fussy ("the lyrics were rather precious for my taste") or dismissive ("here's your precious ring!"), and an earlier 18th century meaning of "worthless"; none of which seem relevant here.

Here are a couple of examples of the utter/complete/etc usage in newspaper articles, within about 40 years or so earlier - when Freeman was in his mid-twenties.

[A precious scoundrel.](https://paperspast.natlib.govt.nz/newspapers/AS18870510.2.44)

[A precious villain.](https://www.nytimes.com/1886/08/19/archives/a-precious-villain-at-large.html)

Comment: Note that  Austin's writing was a bit old-fashioned even for his time, in many ways it echos the 1880s or 1890s.